# How to save datetime with local time zone in mysql using momentjs

Tags: node.js, date, momentjs, locale

I read many stack overflow pages or else, but I don't understand why the datetime is always saved in MySQL database in UTC format although local time is UTC+2.

I try

```
const now = moment().local();
```

or

```
const now = moment(new Date()).local().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
console.log(now)    <-- display the right local time (UTC+2)
```

But once `now` is sent to the database, time is saved in UTC format.

Why ?

The database used is MySQL and `@@global.time.zone`is set to `SYSTEM`. My system is well configured to UTC+2.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `moment-timezone` for this purpose:

```
const moment = require('moment-timezone');
const date = moment("2019-01-01 14:40:00");
console.log(date.tz("Asia/Kolkata").format());
```

Comment: If I understand well, moment-timezone allows me to convert a datetime explicitly to any timezone. So what is the goal of `moment().local()` ? And why `console.log(now)` is ok but not the same value saved in my database ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answers to my questions. In fact, the problem does not come from Momentjs, but Sequelize I use to save my data in the database.
By default Sequelize saves all the datetime format in UTC.